# CodeIgniter How to bring the id of image clicked in the url?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing an web app using codeigniter. When I try to click
an image (using detail method), it doesn't include the ID of the image in the link.

I have tried many times, but it still doesn't work. I've even run the same project on another team member's PC, but it still doesn't work on my PC.

Here's the code:

```
public function detail($url_title, $id = '') {
        // Get user logged in id
        $user_id = $this->auth->userid();

        // Decode url id
        $id = decode_safe_url(@$id);

        // Get survey master info
        // division 0 mean survey, status 0 is not publish
        $survey = $this->egsurveymaster->get(array('id' => @$id, 'division' => '1', 'status != ' => "0"));

        // Redirect if product review is not exist
        if (!@$survey) {
            redirect('andrasurvey');
        }

        // Update read count
        if (isset($_COOKIE['eblo_pcid'])) {
            $this->egsurveymaster->count_read(@$id, $_COOKIE['andra_pcid']);
        }

        // Title
        $this->template->title = asset_title('Andra Survey - ' . @$survey->title);

        // Vars
        $vars = array(
            'contents' => array(
                'master_id' => @$survey->id,
                'review' => $this->_overviewContent(@$survey->id, @$survey),
            ),
            'snsContents' => array(
                'title' => @$survey->title,
                'image' => asset_url(@$survey->image),
                'url' => base_url('andrasurvey/detail/' . url_title(@$survey->title) . '/' . encode_safe_url(@$survey->id)),
                'content' => character_limiter(strip_tags(@$survey->content, 150)),
                'keywords' => trim(@$survey->title) . ', ',
                'username' => 'andraadmin',
            ),
        );

        // Content
        $this->template->content->view(asset_content('detail'), @$vars);

        // publish the template
        $this->template->publish();
    }
```

When I click the image, this is what I get:

> http://localhost:1234/andrasurvey/survey/detail/umur-anda-yang-seharusnya/

I really need your help, 
Thank you.

Comment: // Update read count
            if (isset($_COOKIE['andra_pcid'])) {
                $this->egsurveymaster->count_read(@$id, $_COOKIE['andra_pcid']);
            }

Comment: why are you using the `@` symbol in your variables? just wondering

Comment: check whether the variabel is null or not